# QT exe file doesn't appear to run

Tags: qt, qml

I wrote a program in Qt:

- Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource)
- based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
- Windows 8.1 64-bit

My program is running fine in Qt creator.But I want to execute it in other computers on all Windows without installing Qt. I copied all required `.dll` files next to the .exe file (Release build) with `windeployqt.exe`.

[image]

When I start the.exe, nothing happens.
No GUI showing up, no error that a .dll is missing. But I see my application in 'ProcessExplorer'.
This happen for even very simple program.

Here's a screenshot of my Dependency Walker screen for simple application:
[image]

Comment: You need a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Does the same thing happen to you with a very simple "Hello World" program, or is it specific to the features of your "myapp"?  What happens when you add some print statements during the program initialization or window initializations--which run and which don't?  If you add a timer and ask it to print out to the console every few seconds is it printing?  When you use the API to ask if it thinks the main window is visible, what does it say?  Etc...

Comment: try to add libstdc++(yorvesrion).dll from: Qt installation path/your qt version/your compiler/bin/.
also you can try to use dependency walker to check if you forgot to add any other library

Comment: Same thing happen in very simple "Hello World" program.

Comment: A few other libs that you may need: `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll` ... this is just from a v.simple hello world GUI app in windows using Qt5... the versions may differ slightly. (edit...ah, by mine is mingw not msvc compiler)

Comment: I added libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll and libstdc++.dll but was useless.

Comment: Try manually copying the original Qt5Core.dll to this folder, the problem may be in the patched DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and as you, I had no error message or any output whatsoever. I solved the issue when I added the QML path to my deployment.

On this page, [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html), you will see the commmand:
*windeployqt --qmldir < path-to-app-qml-files> < path-to-app-binary>*

Here the command with the qml flag.

```
C:\Qt\5.10.1\mingw53_32\bin\windeployqt.exe --qmldir C:\My_project C:\My_project\build-My_project_MinGW_32bit-Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using QML.
did you have a look at stdout / stderr? I have had that problem when my QML file was not loadable / path was incorrect. 
Also settings environment variable QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1 helped me to spot these kind of problems.